# My code is written twice for uncomprehensible reasons

Tags: c++

This code is written in C++ and for reasons that I don't quite understand it is written twice.
I would expect that after inputting a random char it would display the char once and the String lower to it once as well. But I don't get this as output. What am I missing?

Solution: Adding a cin.ignore() statement disregards the return that is read in as well.
Making my code go through the loop once.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    char letter;

    letter = cin.get();
    while (letter!= 'X')
    {
        cout << letter << endl;
        cout << "this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons";                
        letter = cin.get();
    }
}
```

Example:
If I were to write in cmd scrn `c`, I'd get a `c` back + twice the phrase `this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons`. So what I thought to be the output

```
c
this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons
```

is actually

```
c
this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons
this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons
```

Comment: the code is written twice? please rephrase your question...

Comment: what is your _exact_ input and output?

Comment: Because he wants a single character, and cin.get() is for that purpose.

Comment: I edited question , and I am using that command because my assignment from univ tells me so...

Comment: What a horrendous "comment"

Comment: Try cin.sync() after every cin.get() to clear the input buffer, to make sure there is not any newline or something like this left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as everyone already mentioned, `cin` will append the newline marker `\n` every time you hit enter. another solution is to place `cin.ignore();` after every `cin.get();`.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    char letter;

    letter = cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    while (letter!= 'X')
    {
          cout<<letter<<endl;
          cout<<"this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons";
          letter= cin.get();
          cin.ignore();
          }
}
```

Comment: That does not answer the question at all. You do not explain why but use a workaround to skip stream characters.

Comment: @Artur i was the 3rd or maybe even 4th person to answer; others already explained the problem, i just provided another solution that wasn't already mentioned.

Comment: @stellarossa: 2me looks like only elnigno's comment is close to explaining why but he has not answered - only commented. All showed workarounds or how to do it better.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot about the newline.
cin reads *every* character, which includes the newline you type after typing your character.
If you don't want this behaviour, you have to specifically check for newline.

```
while (letter!= 'X')
{
      if (letter == '\n')
      {
          letter = cin.get();
          continue;
      }
      cout<<letter<<endl;
      cout<<"this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons";
      letter= cin.get();
}
```

Comment: But he's using cin.get(), which should return a single character. Am I wrong?

Comment: It returns a single character, but the next time it gets executed it returns the next character, which is presumably the newline. (Could be other chars typed before the newline)

Comment: I see, but from the question it seems that he's only typing a character, not pressing enter/return/newline as well.

Comment: if `letter == '\n'` you go in endless loop

Comment: By default, you only get input after you hit return. I don't know exactly why, but you have to specifically turn it off. (I believe it's a shell thing, but don't quote me on that)

Comment: @llnk Indeed, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading every character with the unformatted `get()` function, including the newline character each time you hit return.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could use formatted input (`cin >> c`) to skip all whitespace; or you could test each character and ignore things like newline that don't interest you; or you could use `getline(cin, some_string)` to read a whole line, and then process that.

Comment: @BURNS: "Unformatted input" means you get each character, exactly as it appears in the input stream, with no funny business. "Formatted input", using `>>`, can skip whitespace, extract words, and perform conversions to numeric types.

Answer (score 2):

When you type in a character the new-line character (from pressing enter) is also in your input buffer.

[From the C-Reference:](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/)

> The delimiting character is not extracted from the input sequence if found, and remains there as the next character to be extracted from the stream (see getline for an alternative that does discard the delimiting character).

Just use a `cin.sync()` after every `cin.get()` to clear the buffer and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

The text 'this will be written twice..' will not necessarily print twice.

Type 'qwerty' + ENTER and your stream will have "qwerty\n" within and you'll see this output:

```
this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons
this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons
this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons
this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons
this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons
this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons
this will be written twice for ununderstandable reasons
```

Exactly that many as string "qwerty\n" has characters.
The problem is that

> cin.get()

Puts all chars that you type into a stream/buffer (not your letter char) but handles **one** char every cin.get() invocation.

When you type 'abcXd' + enter - the program will print above line 3 times and stop on X.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because cin.get() reads `new-line` character too. Try to press `Enter` without any symbols or type some string, like `abc`.
You need to handle it, e.g.:

```
while (letter = cin.get()) {
    if (!isalpha(letter)) { continue; }
    // handling user inputted alpha
}
```